# Button Click window phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I need to change button content when the button pressed but i call function open message box inside buttonClick so the content didn't apper untill the message box closed.

code sample:

```
private void B1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        B1.content="X";
        DisplayMessage();
    }
```

I want to show X befor message.
I try to use MouseLeftButtonDown/Up but it didn't work.

Comment: what's in `DisplayMessage()`?

Comment: set DisplayMessage function as it is and cut "B1.content=x" and paste it  MouseLeftButtonDown/Up event...bcos x appear when click event is finish so its not possible in both function work same event

Comment: @Xyroid DisplayMessage() open MessagebBox.show(something);

Comment: @MansinhDodiya MouseLeftButtonDown didn't work when i press the button  i put break point in side it but it didn't get inside

Comment: @Raghda Ramadan:use MouseLeftButtonUp event and mark it if you write both function than it always occure when all event exicuted.try with this event and update me

Comment: So you want to show user, button content being changed and then you want to open the message box, am I right?

Comment: @MansinhDodiya i try MouseLeftButtonUp  but the same as Down didn't go throw it

Answer (score 1):

You can use delay to perform what you want.

```csharp
private async void B1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    B1.content="X";
    await Task.Delay(1000);     // 1000 is miliseconds
    DisplayMessage();
}
```